# How can I calculate discounts with conditions or if statements in Excel?

Tags: excel

I have an excel spreadsheet that has 5 columns titled "Product Cost", "Percentage Discount", "Discount Amount", "Head Office Contribution" and "Franchise contribution".

The first the columns are populated by a form. For example "$10 000" (Product Cost), "10%"(Percentage Discount) and "$1000" (Discount Amount - 10% of $10 000).

If the percentage discount is less than or equal to 15%, then "Head Office" and "Franchise" will both contribute an equal amount, 50:50, to make up the discount. i.e in the above example, the "Head Office" would contribute $500 (Discount Amount/2) and the same for the "Franchise".

If the discount is above 15%, then the Head Office will only pay 50:50 up to 10% then the remaining 5% is paid by the franchise. e.g. if the discount is 18% on $10 000, Head office will view it as 10% and therefore pay $500, leaving the franchise to pay $500 of their half of the 10% plus the additional 8%.

How do I work this out using excel conditions?[Image of spreadsheet attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/quYS8.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For head office use formula:

```
=IF(B2<=15%,C2*0.5,A2*0.05)
```

for franchise:

```
=C2-D2
```

[image]